# CSS. Fixed vertical divs align

Tags: css

If do not use `width: 270px;` all `<div class="top-results">` align horizontally, but I need every div on new line. How is it possible to replace `width: 270px;` in css?

```
<div id="top-results-wrapper">
    <div class="top-results">
        <span class="top-results-number">208</span>
        <span class="top-results-car">BMW X6</span>
        <span class="top-results-result">13.552</span>
    </div>
    <div class="top-results">
        <span class="top-results-number">209</span>
        <span class="top-results-car">SUBARU IMPREZA</span>
        <span class="top-results-result">11.263</span>
    </div>
</div>

#top-results-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: It's on a different line for me. Can you elaborate? Check the code in jsFiddle [jsfiddle.net/wYCLR/](http://jsfiddle.net/wYCLR/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here, just set .top-results to `display:block`

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/46FyP/